# Android Menu Item

Tags: android

I'm trying to load an activity, when an option is selected from the menu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_flash:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FlashActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_color:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FlashActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;          break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;

}
```

but it keep to give me intent error

Comment: Have you declared `FlashActivity` in your Manifest?

Comment: Why do you have two menu items that do the same?

Comment: i just a mistake each one lead to different activity the error is this Duplicate local variable intent which i don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change with this:

```
@Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.item1:
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, FlashActivity.class);
             this.startActivity(intent);;

            return true;
       case R.id.item2:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FlashActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);

           return true;
        default:
           return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
```

Comment: I do not think the problem is that is he is not ending the caller activity. It is valid to not call finish() in the caller activity.

Comment: Ya....I know that...my mean not particular focus that the problem will be solved because of finish().

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(youractivity.this, FlashActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Change to above code...

Comment: why to use youractivity.this if he can get contex directly bcoz he is not using anonymous inner class

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the FlashActivity declare in manifest file.Then try this..

```
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_flash:
        openFlashmenu();
         return true;
    case R.id.menu_color:
        openFlashmenu();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

 public void openFlashmenu(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FlashActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
         }
```

Comment: why to a use getApplicationContext() if he can get contex directly bcoz he is not using anonymous inner class

Comment: @Shakeeb Ayaz getApplicationContext() get the base activity where it calls

Comment: I am always ready to correct myself..what u are doig is correct but Wat i am saying is If you are not in annonymous inner class then you can get context by directly saying `this` no need of calling other function to get context

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz I thought his application have wide classes.For that  suggested getApplicationContext().

Comment: it give me Duplicate local variable intent

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.menu_flash:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FlashActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared FlashActivity in your manifest file??

if not,add this to your manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".FlashActivity" >
    </activity>
```